# How to get new encrypted url on validation page in JMETER test execution

Tags: jmeter

I am new to Jmeter, and caught with an issue with handling requests from jmeter, my test-case is following:

1. Applicant has to click on apply online from home page, which will redirect user to a new validation page.
2. Enter Token No and other details on this page and click on validate button, which will redirect to form with number of details to be filled.
3. Fill all required details and submit.

In general it seems very easy, but to protect application developers has been added two query string "Value" and "Digest" with normal url, these two values are server-encrypted information using current session_id as key.
Now to execute steps 2 & 3 I need to supply new generated value and digest.

Please guide how I can retrieve values which receive after clicking on button.
As in tree results listener it is still on same page in response on which i send request to server, which fails to retrieve new value.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract content from previous responses to use it in later requests using the Post Processor test element "Regular Expression Extractor". Think of a regular expression matching these values. Somehow the server must tell the browser what they are, either in a http 32 redirect or somewhere as hidden imput form fields. You can extract it from there into a variable and use that one in the subsequent http request's GET or POST parameters.

Comment: **Yes it helps** but in my case I need to design a webpage/class to get that value in response first then I applied concept of regular exp extractoer ....
thanks for ur response.